# setting instance for forms in UpdateView

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

i have an UpdateView with a couple of forms and i'm trying to understand how to set the instance for the other form because the first form work just fine but the second form is always empty and i cant figure out how to set the instance for that modelform .

```
class ProfileUpdateView(UpdateView):
    # model = User
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    form_class = UserForm
    second_form_class = ClientForm

    template_name = 'accounts/update.html'



    def get_object(self):
        user = get_object_or_404(User , username__iexact=self.kwargs.get('username'))
        return user


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        user = self.object
        profile = Client.objects.get(id = user.clients.id)
        context = super(ProfileUpdateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        if user.is_client and 'ClientForm' not in context:
            context['client_form'] = self.second_form_class(self.request.GET, instance=profile )
    return context
```

### models

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    gender_choice  =(
        ('Male','Male'),
        ('Female','Female'),
        )
    is_artisan     = models.BooleanField('artisan status', default=False)
    is_client      = models.BooleanField('client status', default=False)
    avatar         = models.ImageField(null=True ,blank=True)
    birth_day      = models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)
    birth_location = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True ,blank=True)
    adresse        = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True ,blank=True)
    gender         = models.CharField(max_length=6,choices=gender_choice,)
    phone          = models.CharField(max_length=10 ,null=True ,blank=True)

class Client(models.Model):
    client_choice = (
        ('erson','person'),
        ('company','company'),
        )
    client_type = models.CharField(max_length=10,choices=client_choice,)
    user        = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='clients')
```

### forms

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email','avatar','adresse','birth_location','birth_day' ,'gender' ,'phone')



class ClientForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = ('client_type',)
```

the question now how/where can i set the instance for the second form and where is the first form instance is set .

Answer (score 0):

Is that a typo in get_context_data? Should it be:

```
if user.is_client and 'client_form' not in context:
    context['client_form'] = self.second_form_class(self.request.GET, instance=profile)
```

The first form is set in UpdateView's super class FormMixin.get_context_data (which in turn calls FormMixin.get_form()). [Docs for FormMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin)

Comment: yes it is a typo indeed thanks for that . you mean i have to override get_form() and set the other forms instances ?

Comment: @LeLouch No what you have with the typo fixed should work I think. I just mentioned that about FormMixin to answer your question about where is the first form instantiated.

Comment: well the 2nd form is empty still the instance isnt working on the other form

Comment: @LeLouch hmmm, okay, what about your ClientForm?

Comment: i add forms as well

Comment: @LeLouch Okay last thing I can think of is the template, can you show that?

Comment: dude the  template has nothing to do with it ,everything renders fine just empty no data on it